# Implementing iOS Firebase Instant Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement iOS messaging app using Firebase. I have been trying to follow this guide by Google:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

And a part of it is enabling Push Notifications, which I can't get the key for because I don't have a developer subscription.

Is there any way around it? Can I implement Firebase messaging on iOS in any other way?

Comment: No, you can't implement any kind of notification service without having paid developer account. @Ofri

Comment: So I have to subscribe for the atleast $100 a year membership, right ?

Comment: Yes, u have to @Ofri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this using firebase but you can try using pub/sub services like pubnub